# \verbatimInput prints unnecessary lines at the end

Tags: beamer, verbatim, fancyvrb

`test.tex` contains the following code

```
\begin{itemize}[(i)]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
```

When I use this file using `\verbatimInput` it prints `c@FancyVerbLi` as the final line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \fvset{fontsize=\small,frame=single, numbers=left,numbersep=3pt}
    \VerbatimInput{test.tex}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I remove it from the output?

---

Edit: The output that I get is

[image]

Comment: I don't get the additional line. Which beamer version are you using? Which engine?

Comment: @samcarter I have updated the post. I am using Beamer 3.50

Comment: I'm also using 3.50: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjWR4.png Which engine do you use? pdflatex or something else?

Comment: It is pdflatex.

Comment: Can you add your .log file?

Comment: It is a very lengthy file. How can I upload it?

Comment: If it is too long for the question, maybe pastebin.com could be a workaround

Comment: Refer this link [link] (https://pastebin.com/MQB7BrMv)

Comment: Can you try to update your miktex distribution?

Comment: I get that "error" too. I find that it goes away if I leave an empty line at the end of `test.tex`.

Comment: @samcarter I updated miktex. But it didn't help.

Comment: @Troy. Yes. It worked. Any reason?

Comment: @Troy Which operating system do you have?

Comment: @S.Perera hmm no idea, sorry. I don't use fancyvrb myself.

Comment: @samcarter Windows 10.

Comment: @Troy Might be some system specific behaviour of file ending. On osx it works without an empty line.

Comment: @samcarter Confirmed: it seems like a Windows thing.

Answer (score 6):

The quick fix is to leave an empty line in your input file `test.tex`, like so:

**test.tex**

```
\begin{itemize}[(i)]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
    \fvset{fontsize=\small,frame=single, numbers=left,numbersep=3pt}
    \VerbatimInput{test.tex}
\end{document}
```

will give, as desired:

[image]

---

It does seem like a bug though. I'll leave this here if anyone is able to debug:
If we try

```
\begin{itemize}[(i)]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}
four
```

then the result is

[image]

and with

```
\begin{itemize}[(i)]
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
\end{itemize}
a very long phrase zz
```

[image]

so the only reason why leaving a new line works is because there's 0 characters on that line. As far as I can see anyway.